# How do I make a "private" RESTful resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

Ok, so this is maybe a very basic question about REST concepts or Rails security in general, but bear with me.

I have a google map in my main page, I would like to get all the latitudes/longitudes from the companies in my DB so I can create the markers and show them.

So, I created a resource that's http://mywebsite.com/companies/locations, it returns a json object with the company ids and each of their latitude longitudes.

Now, this is probably the right way to do it, but I keep getting this feeling that its a bit too... exposed?

I mean, anyone could just type that on the browser and get all the companies we have. That doesn't sound very secure.

In my mind there would be a way for only that javascript ajax call to get the information and "hide" it from the public eye, or is this just a case of security through obscurity?

Is there a common piece of knowledge I'm missing or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any data that needs to be sent to the client browser (i.e. anything to be used by JavaScript) is vulnerable. There is no way to reliably protect such data.

Comment: That makes sense... it just seems so easy to just grab the information.

Comment: Yep, it is. The real question is whether that's something to worry about. Usually, it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Read up on [HTTP authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). Watch the [screencast on HTTP authentication in Rails](http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1).

There are other ways to do authentication with REST, but this is the most 'natural' and standardized one.

**[EDIT]** Sorry, re-read your question again. If you need the data to be displayed to a user, there is absolutely no way to hide it. Whichever obscure way you'd make up to hide the URL, the request could be easily captured using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) (for example), along with the response data.

**[EDIT 2]** Well, you could encrypt the data serverside and then decrypt it within Javascript, but still the decrypting code is available to anyone. Besides, I'm fairly sure you can get the Google Maps object from the debug console and just read the placemarks from it.

Comment: yeah, I get it. Basically anything that comes from the server to the client is readable in some way or another by an external source.